# How can I make a model method editable through a dependent field in django admin list display

Tags: django, django-admin

The scenario:
I have a model like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Appointment(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    topic = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, null=True, help_text="Topic to be discussed at the meeting"
    )
    medium = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Meet link")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.date_and_time}"

    @property
    @admin.display(
        ordering="time",
        description="Date and time of the appointment",
    )
    def date_and_time(self):
        return self.time.strftime("%b %d, %I:%M %p")
```

With an admin model

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Appointment


@admin.register(Appointment)
class AppointmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierachy = "time"

    list_display = (
        "date_and_time",
        "medium",
    )

    list_editable = (
        "date_and_time",
        "medium",
    )
```

As shown in the code, I want to use a derived model method (date_and_time) in the Django list display, while making it editable through its dependent field "time".
Of course, as expected, the above code throws an error because I included "date_and_time", which is the derived model method and not a field, in the list_editable tuple, I cannot add "time" as it doesn't exist in the list_display at all, instead it is represented as the date_and_time method which only formats the time field btw.

My question: Is there a way to have the formatted DateTime (which is what the date_and_time does) displayed in the list table, allowing editing through the time field on which it is fully dependent.

Comment: Don't use your custom property at all, just use the `time` field. Your custom method just applies formatting to `time` but if it's going to be list editable then it will be rendered as inputs anyway

Comment: Thank you @IainShelvington , I initially thought the field being editable means I could click an icon or button to make it an input field, the fact that it stays an input field permanently is actually ugly and I have decided to have no editables. Again, thank you for your help.